# Hatcher Exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

One of Hatcher's exercises asks me to prove that if we have a polynomial with complex coefficients, and we view it as a continuous map of the Riemann Sphere into itself then the degree of the polynomial coincides with the topological degree. I know that, I can use local degrees in a neighborhood in which the polynomial doesn't vanish, which would make them map homeomorphically, but I don't see how to determine the sign. Any ideas?

Comment: what is topological degree?

Comment: It is the coefficient you get from the induced map in the singular homology groups.

Comment: They define it in Hatcher pg. 134.

Comment: Locally, any nonconstant holomorphic function has the form $z \mapsto z^k$, where $k \geq 0$. That's orientation-preserving, and the local degree is $k$.